# VOTE SYSTEM - Counting the max vote

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sum

I have this .php where I have to count the max vote from the database

```
SELECT std.fname, std.lname, COUNT(v.cand_id)
FROM vote v, student std, candidate ca, position pos
WHERE v.cand_id = ca.stud_id AND ca.pos_id = 1 AND ca.stud_id = std.id
```

The problem is that the count is off, it shows 70 votes while when I count it on the database its only 11 votes. I think it's counting all the votes rather than on the specific person on the `COUNT(v.cand_id)`.

This table is about counting the votes and showing the highest person who got the vote.

$que1 = mysql_query ($sql1,$con);

```
    while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($que1))
        { 


            echo "President: "; echo "".$row1['fname']; echo " ".$row1['lname']; echo " having ".$row1['v.cand_id']; echo " votes"; 

            echo "<br>";    
        }
```

Comment: `FROM vote v, student std ...` gives you a cross product of all the tables! Use [MySQL JOINs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
SELECT 
  std.fname, 
  std.lname, 
  COUNT(v.cand_id) TotalVotes
FROM vote            AS v
INNER JOIN candidate AS ca  ON v.cand_id  = ca.stud_id
INNER JOIN student   AS std ON ca.stud_id = std.id
INNER JOIN position  AS pos ON ca.pos_id  = pos.id
WHERE ca.pos_id = 1
GROUP BY std.fname, 
         std.lname;
```

This will counting the votes for each user.

To show only the highest person who got the total votes, try this:

```
SELECT 
  std.fname, 
  std.lname, 
  COUNT(v.cand_id) TotalVotes
FROM vote            AS v
INNER JOIN candidate AS ca  ON v.cand_id  = ca.stud_id
INNER JOIN student   AS std ON ca.stud_id = std.id
INNER JOIN position  AS pos ON ca.pos_id  = pos.id
WHERE ca.pos_id = 1
GROUP BY std.fname, 
         std.lname
ORDER BY TotalVotes DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**Things to note:**

- Please try to avoid the old join syntax using the `WHERE` clause the way you did, and start using the explicit ANSI-92 join syntax instead. In the query you posted, you were joining the tables in the `WHERE` clause, but for table `position pos` there were no joining condition, and this might be the reason why you were getting incorrect data, because in this case it was cross joining the two tables instead.
- Also, try to avoid using the aggregate functions with columns that are not in an aggregate functions, without the use of `GROUP BY` clause the way you did, it will work for MySQL, but it is a good practice to do so.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add this, I'm using this with .php file

Comment: @user2172157 - OK, just replace the query you are using with this query inside your php code.

Comment: I used 'TotalVotes' in echo "President: "; echo "".$row1['fname']; echo " ".$row1['lname']; echo " having ".$row1['TotalVotes']; echo " votes"; and it's showing only Person ABC having "1" votes it only shows 1 vote

Comment: @user2172157 Have you tested this query on MySQL directly? try to run the query only and test it. Also, try to post some sample data from the three tables with the desired output that you are looking for.

Comment: I got it working by removing DISTINCT, Thanks for the help man. :)